# JQuery : How to add list of objects in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

It's one of my first time I using `JQuery/AJAX` and I would like to get your help in order to give a list of objects in my dropdown field.

I have this function :

```
function get_sub_method_options(keep_cur) {
  var sel_option = $('select#id_method-group').find("option:selected");
  var sel_val = sel_option.val();
  console.log(sel_val);
  if (sel_val === '') {
    console.log('none sorting group');
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value=""> test </option>'); //here add list of all submethods
    return;
  }

  data = {
    'test_method': $('select#id_method-test_method').find("option:selected").val(),
    'group': sel_val
  };
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: '{% url 'ajax_method_submethod' %}',
    data: data

  }).done(function (result) {
    reset_select('id_method-sub_method');
    for (var i = 0; i < result['results'].length; i++) {
      if (keep_cur > 0 & keep_cur == result['results'][i].id)
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + result['results'][i].id + '" selected>' + result['results'][i].text + '</option>');
      else
        $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + result['results'][i].id + '">' + result['results'][i].text + '</option>');
    }
    ;
  });
}
```

And I have a Python/Django function :

```
def ajax_method_submethod(request):
    test_method_id = request.GET.get("test_method", "")
    group_id = request.GET.get("group", "")
    sub_methods_all = SubMethod.objects.all()
    sub_methods = Method.objects.filter(test_method_id=test_method_id).filter(
        group_id=group_id
    )

    results2 = []
    for item in sub_methods_all:
        results2.append({'id': item.id, 'text': item.name})
    print(results2)

    results = []
    for item in sub_methods:
        results.append({'id': item.sub_method.id, 'text': item.sub_method.name})

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'err': 'nil', 'results': results, 'results2': results2}), content_type='application/json')
```

I would like to import into my dropdown field values from `results2` (python file) when I have `sel_val` is empty :

```
if (sel_val === '') {
   ...
}
```

So how I could rewrite this part :

```
if (sel_val === '') {
    console.log('none sorting group');
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value=""> test </option>'); //here add list of all submethods
    return;
  }
```

Like this :

```
if (sel_val === '') {
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < result['results2'].length; i++) {
      $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + result['results2'][i].id + '">' + result['results2'][i].text + '</option>'); //here add list of all submethods
    }
    return;
  }
```

with `for loop` and append all elements from `results2` to my dropdown field ? The issue is actually with `result['results2']`

Hopfully it's readable and understandable.

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

As @Darren Crabb said, it's a possible out of scope.

So I rewrote my JS like this :

```
if (!sel_val) {
    reset_select('id_method-sub_method');
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    var all = "{{ results2 }}";
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + all[i].id + '">' + all[i].text + '</option>'); //here add list of all submethods
    }
    return;
  }
```

And I defined in my python file : `context['results2'] = SubMethod.objects.all()`

I get this :

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the "Like this" approach shown? SHow us what `result['results2']` looks like

Comment: "The issue is actually with result['results2']"...and what exactly _is_ the issue? What goes wrong?

Comment: I get an issue in my console : `result is not defined`. I don't know where I have to set this piece of code. Furthermore, I don't know if it's correct to make things like this because it's my first JQuery/Ajax code. In my python file, `results2 = [{'id': 449, 'text': '50% cell culture infective dose (CCID50)'}, {'id': 176, 'text': 'Acetic acid in synthetic peptides'}, ...`

Comment: Might be worth checking the network activity in your console, especially on the file being accessed by the ajax call. This should show you the headers, response etc. for each file listed (if you click on them) where you can check to make sure the correct results are being passed back to your client-side code. This happens in Firefox console at least - not sure about other browsers. That often helps a lot when working with ajax.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access 'result' out of scope. As far as I can tell result is only defined in the return callback of the ajax function where it will contain the response of the call, it's not defined anywhere in the top part of the code.

Comment: @DarrenCrabb I defined `var all = "{{ results2 }}";` and in my views.py file `context['results2'] = SubMethod.objects.all()`. It seems to work, I have my list but all objects are `undefined`. I will edit my question to show you the result.

Comment: it may also be worth checking the 'dataType' parameter on the ajax call, to make sure it's set to expect the json or whatever result you are expecting to receive. I've had fun with that being set wrong before.